# Usercontrol pageload events fires AFTER ASPX pageload event

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

1. I have a user control (`WODetails.ascx`) that gets `WOCode` and fill some fields related to work order.
2. I have a `ASPX` page that contains a grid and above user control once i click on grid control (`ROWCommand` Event fires)

I want to call pageload event once rowcommand event fires, beacuse rowcommand retruns `WOCOde` and my usercontrol should fill fields accordingly. But problem is usercontrol pageload events fires after `ASPX` pageload event fires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Page_Load` is an event called by the .NET framework, it is intended to notify the `Controls` of the stage of the page life cycle. It is not meant for this kind of communication.

If you want to communicate with the `UserControl`, why not writing a custom method on the `UserControl`?

```
public class WODetails : UserControl
{
    ...

    public void DoMyStuff(object WOCOde)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

And on the ASPX, you just call it when you need:

```
void grdDummy_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    object WOCOde = GetWOCode(e);
    WODetails.DoMyStuff(WOCOde);
}
```

Comment: Dear.
i have already tried this . My user controls contains some ASPX controls and calling custom method does loads the controls. it retruns exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
For that i need to call pageload event then calling any method will work. i guess

Comment: Firstly, i have no way to be aware of what you have or not tried. Because maybe you just didn't make it clear on the question. Secondly, that exception that it is "returning" is kind of self explanatory. Just debug your code. I think its clear that my answer contains only pseudo-code.

Comment: is there any way to call my Usercontrol's Pageload event on grid row command?

Comment: Pageload event is called by the framework. There is indeed ways of calling it yourself, but please, explain to me why would it solve your problem?